# Mail body not forwarding

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, gmail-api

I am using gmail sdk.
And I am stuck on forwarding a mail.

I am using following code to forward a mail.

```
NSString * strToBeRep ;
for(GTLGmailMessagePartHeader *header in message.payload.headers){
    if([header.name isEqualToString:@"From"]){
        strToBeRep = header.value;
    }
    break;
}

GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:nil];
NSString *strMessageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To:%@\nSubject:%@\nThreadId:%@\n\n\n",@"forwardingPersonMail@gmail.com",@"Fwd:",message.threadId];
NSData *messageBody = [strMessageBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GTLGmailMessage *message =[[GTLGmailMessage alloc]init];
query.userId = @"me";
NSString *base64Encoded = [messageBody base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

message.raw = base64Encoded;

base64Encoded = [base64Encoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"];
base64Encoded = [base64Encoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"-"];
//message.payload.body = self.mail.mail.payload.body;
message.threadId = self.mail.mail.threadId;
query.message = message;

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultForNewMessage:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

How to append the body of forwarded mail.
The mail is been forwarded in same thread.
But problem is that the mail body is not forwarding i.e mail body is nil.

Comment: Do you received error message? in your request body, you must supply a Users.messages resource with the following properties as metadata. The 'raw' property must be base64url encoded string. dont forget to turn on the 'Gmail API' in your console. Have check this documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But the problem has been solved